# Is there an google (REST) API to list the Admin Roles in a Google Apps account?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I can view the Admin roles and the users is each admin role in my Google Apps account from the Admin Console. 
The default admin roles being:

- Super Admin
- Group Admin
- Services Admin

I wanted to know if i could programmatically list all the Admin Groups and list all the users in each Admin Group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_user), you can retrieve a user's admin status, `isAdmin` (super admin) and `isDelegatedAdmin` (assigned an Admin role). Unfortunately, these are both boolean responses and, AFAIK, you cannot pull the specific role details.